# User can fill two related divs on purpose or by random generation — how do I store the selected values in local storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have two related divs (an image and its corresponding label) that a user can fill in one of two ways: by either 1) selecting the image directly or 2) clicking a "random" button that selects from an array.

HTML for the divs that get filled ("#currentLabelA" and "#currentRhythm_A"):

```
<div class="currentSelection">
     <div class="selectedLabelA" id="currentLabelA">A</div>
     <div class="selectedRhythm currentRhythm_A" id="currentRhythm_A"><img src="../images/RM-0.1.png" width="172" height="60" alt="0-1" /></div>
</div>
```

The first way to fill the divs is by clicking the label of the image to select it (there are many more choices, almost 100; I'm abridging it to 3 here). This fills #currentLabelA with the name of the rhythm and #currentRhythm_A with the image of the rhythm:

```
                    <div class="tabbertab">
                        <h3>3</h3>
                        <section class="allRhythms">
                            <h6>Tap play to listen. Tap number to select.</h6>
                            <div class="RM_rhythm">
                                <audio id="3.1" preload='none'>
                                <source src='../audio/3.1.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='../audio/3.1.ogg' type='audio/ogg' />
                                </audio>
                                <button onclick="document.getElementById('3.1').play()"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></button>
                                <a href="#" class="button">3-1</a>
                                <img src="../images/RM-3.1.png" width="172" height="60" alt="3-1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="RM_rhythm">
                                <audio id="3.2" preload='none'>
                                <source src='../audio/3.2.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='../audio/3.2.ogg' type='audio/ogg' />
                                </audio>
                                <button onclick="document.getElementById('3.2').play()"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></button>
                                <a href="#" class="button">3-2</a>
                                <img src="../images/RM-3.2.png" width="172" height="60" alt="3-2">
                            </div>
                            <div class="RM_rhythm">
                                <audio id="3.3" preload='none'>
                                <source src='../audio/3.3.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='../audio/3.3.ogg' type='audio/ogg' />
                                </audio>
                                <button onclick="document.getElementById('3.3').play()"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></button>
                                <a href="#" class="button">3-3</a>
                                <img src="../images/RM-3.3.png" width="172" height="60" alt="3-3">
                            </div>

                        </section>
                    </div><!-- end this tab -->
```

The alternate way to fill the divs is by clicking the "Random A" button:

```
<input type="button" id="btnSearchA" class="btn btn-2 btn-2c" value="Random A" onclick="GetValueA();" />
                                        <p id="message" style="display:none!important;"></p>
```

Here's the javascript for filling the divs in these two different ways:

```
<!-- fill currentRhythm_A -->   
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').on('click', function() {
        var imagewanted = $(this).closest('.RM_rhythm').find('img').attr("src");
        $('.currentRhythm_A').html("<img src='" + imagewanted + "' />");
        var currentlabel = $(this).closest('.RM_rhythm').find('audio').attr("id");
        $('#currentLabelA').html(currentlabel);
        $('#playA').html("<source src='../audio/" + currentlabel + ".mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='../audio/" + currentlabel + ".ogg' type='audio/ogg' />");
        $('#playA').load(); 
   });
});
</script>   


<!-- generate a random rhythm for A --> 
<script>

function GetValueA(){
    var myarray= new Array("0.1","1.1","2.1","2.2","2.3","2.4","2.5","2.6","2.7","2.8","2.9","2.10","2.11","2.12","2.13","2.14","2.15","3.1","3.2","3.3","3.4","3.5","3.6","3.7","3.8","3.9","3.10","3.11","3.12","3.13","3.14","3.15","4.1","4.2","4.3","4.4","4.5","4.6","4.7","4.8","4.9","4.10","4.11","4.12","4.13","4.14","4.15","5.1","5.2","5.3","5.4","5.5","5.6","5.7","5.8","5.9","5.10","5.11","5.12","5.13","5.14","5.15","6.1","6.2","6.3","6.4","6.5","6.6","6.7","6.8","6.9","6.10","6.11","6.12","6.13","6.14","6.15");
    var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
    //alert(random);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=random;
        $('.currentRhythm_A').html("<img src='../images/RM-" + random + ".png' />");
        $('#currentLabelA').html(random);
        $('#playA').html("<source src='../audio/" + random + ".mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='../audio/" + random + ".ogg' type='audio/ogg' />");
        $('#playA').load(); 
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
}
</script>
```

I am trying to figure out how to store these images/labels in local storage. I know I need to do something like this for both #currentLabelA and #currentRhythm_A:

```
var A = document.getElementById("currentLabelA");
localStorage.setItem("currentLabelA", A.innerHTML);
currentLabelA.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("currentLabelA");
```

But I can't figure out how to call it. Do I need to call it twice, once in the function for the randomly generated div fill and once in the function for the user-selected div fill? Or can I have it outside those two functions as its own function? I'm new to javascript and can't quite make my tutorials come together for this one. Any help much appreciated!

---

EDITED...
Okay, here's the updated javascript to reflect the answer suggested below. I can see in the console that it is saving the value correctly to local storage, but it's not pre-populating the field with the saved value. So it's setting but not getting. Any further advice?

```
<!-- fill currentRhythm_A -->   
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').on('click', function() {
        var imagewanted = $(this).closest('.RM_rhythm').find('img').attr("src");
        $('.currentRhythm_A').html("<img src='" + imagewanted + "' />");
        var currentlabel = $(this).closest('.RM_rhythm').find('audio').attr("id");
        $('#currentLabelA').html(currentlabel);
        $('#playA').html("<source src='../audio/" + currentlabel + ".mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='../audio/" + currentlabel + ".ogg' type='audio/ogg' />");
        $('#playA').load(); 
        localStorage.setItem("image", imagewanted);
        imagewanted = localStorage.getItem("image");
        localStorage.setItem("label", currentlabel);
        currentlabel = localStorage.getItem("label");
   });
});
</script>   


<!-- generate a random rhythm for A --> 
<script>

function GetValueA(){
    var myarray= new Array("0.1","1.1","2.1","2.2","2.3","2.4","2.5","2.6","2.7","2.8","2.9","2.10","2.11","2.12","2.13","2.14","2.15","3.1","3.2","3.3","3.4","3.5","3.6","3.7","3.8","3.9","3.10","3.11","3.12","3.13","3.14","3.15","4.1","4.2","4.3","4.4","4.5","4.6","4.7","4.8","4.9","4.10","4.11","4.12","4.13","4.14","4.15","5.1","5.2","5.3","5.4","5.5","5.6","5.7","5.8","5.9","5.10","5.11","5.12","5.13","5.14","5.15","6.1","6.2","6.3","6.4","6.5","6.6","6.7","6.8","6.9","6.10","6.11","6.12","6.13","6.14","6.15");
    var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
    //alert(random);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=random;
        $('.currentRhythm_A').html("<img src='../images/RM-" + random + ".png' />");
        $('#currentLabelA').html(random);
        $('#playA').html("<source src='../audio/" + random + ".mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='../audio/" + random + ".ogg' type='audio/ogg' />");
        $('#playA').load(); 
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        localStorage.setItem("random", random);
        random = localStorage.getItem("random");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you need to store these images/labels in local storage?

Comment: This is a program to help people learn how to improvise. Selecting the rhythms gives them a set of assignments for the week. I want the rhythms to persist on the user's screen for the whole week (or until they change them).

Comment: Am totally open to another solution, though, if there's a better way!

Comment: See my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/59105354/6161531

Answer (score 1):

You need to put those calls to set info in localstorage in each of handlers you use. Then you can run your website locally and in devtools check localStroage, in console. There you can do all same things you do in code, set/get items and clear it.

This way, though, you can store any JSON data. With images you need to convert them to string in base64 format, and then can save that string in localStorage, but I wouldn't recommend this, as images usually have big size (like 100Kb) and it is limited amount of data you can put to localStorage. Better to save URL point to image, if you have them already served, or, if there new images, save them on cloud bucket first, and then save link.

Comment: Yes, I do have the images already served, so I should be able to serve the path or part of the path. I appreciate your advice. Can you help point me to where I properly put those calls in each handler?

Comment: Each image URL is string, you just save string, and next time you need it, take that URL string from localStorage and put in place.

Well you have two handlers: 1. User select image 2. User hit random, so in each of them you need to add localStorage.setItem one time, so whichever user choose, result will definitely get to localStorage. And then check in devtools result, calling localStorage.myKey, where myKey is key used to save data.

Comment: Thanks, Ivan, that was helpful. I can see in the console that the value IS being set... I just don't have the "get" part right yet.

Comment: Use MDN docs, they pretty good about various APIs, and play more with devtools console, that is place where I often just write some little snippets of js code to test how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I took a shot at the base idea and tried to make a test that can

- List rhythms
- Randomise a selection
- Save selection (with local storage)
- Clear selection

Take a look and see if there's anything you can use. :)

https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-worker-j9mvo

Files of interest (see left side):

- index.html
- src/index.js
- src/listOfIds.js

Comment: Wow, Jesse, there's a lot here to look at. Thank you so much for taking the time; I'm sure I'll learn a lot from going through it.

Comment: My pleasure. I liked the challenge :)